# Express Router CRUD API. Cannot DELETE

Tags: node.js, api, http, express, postman

Well, I'm reading the MEAN Machine book and following it's examples. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code so it won't make any DELETE request. GET, PUT and POST works as should.

I have this code on my server.js:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
  next();
});

var apiRouter = express.Router();

apiRouter.route('/users/:user_id')
.get( function (req, res) {
    User.findById( req.params.user_id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) res.send (err);
        res.json(user);
    });
})

.put( function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        if (req.body.name) user.name = req.body.name;
        if (req.body.username) user.username = req.body.username;
        if (req.body.password) user.password = req.body.password;

        user.save( function (err){
            if (err) send (err);
            res.json({message: 'User updated'});
    });
})

.delete( function (req, res) {
    User.remove({
        _id: req.params.user_id
    }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        res.json({ message: 'Deleted' });
    });
});
```

});

I have a set of users the Modulus MongoDB database and, when I try to use POSTMAN with localhost:8080/api/users/5610e5576d827dc41fb8e6e, POSTMAN says

```
Cannot DELETE /api/users/5610e5576d827dc41fb8e6e
```

while my Node server with Morgan says

```
DELETE /api/users/5610e5576d827dc41fb8e6e 404
```

Why I'm getting a 404? What Am I doing wrong?

[Full code](https://github.com/Rodmentou/InfinityRPG)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You've placed closing brackets of `put()` in wrong place. So you're defining your `delete` router inside the `put()` router:

This is your code after proper indentation:

```
.put( function (req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function (err, user) {
        if (err) res.send(err);

        if (req.body.name) user.name = req.body.name;
        if (req.body.username) user.username = req.body.username;
        if (req.body.password) user.password = req.body.password;

        user.save( function (err){
            if (err) send (err);
            res.json({message: 'User updated'});
        });
    })

    .delete( function (req, res) {     // <===== defined inside 'put',
        User.remove({
            _id: req.params.user_id
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) return res.send(err);
            res.json({ message: 'Deleted' });
        });
    });
})
```

So, just move the `delete` router outside of `put` router callback